# Implications from $f(z)\in\mathbb{R} \Longleftrightarrow z\in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: complex-analysis, roots

Let $f:D(0,1)\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic function  such that $f(z)\in\mathbb{R} \Longleftrightarrow z\in \mathbb{R}$. How to prove that $f$ has at most one zero on the disk.

---

By hypothesis the zeros of $f(z)$ are real and $\displaystyle f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ , $a_n\in\mathbb{R}$ since $f(z)=\overline{f(\overline{z})}$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If there are two zeros, then the derivative is zero somewhere on the real axis, so it looks locally like $z^n$, right?  Then it seems like the preimage of $\mathbb{R}$ should be more than one line through the critical point...?

Comment: see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/913637/147263)

Comment: @OmranKouba This question is very similar, but the domain is not holomorphically equivalent, so I'd suggest that a priori it may have character different from that one.

Comment: @Travis, But the proof is straightforwardly  adaptable, because this is a local property.

Comment: @OmranKouba Yes, I agree that the answers are essentially the same, but the questions, at least a priori, are not.