# Analytical function with positive imaginary part on the upper half plane

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be an analytical function on the whole complex plane, with $\Im f(z) = 0$ when $\Im z = 0$ and $\Im f(z) \ge 0$ when $\Im z > 0$. It can be found quickly that linear functions $f(z)=az + b$, where $a \ge 0, b \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfy the requirements. Are
there any other possibilities? Can we find a general form of $f(z)$?

Comment: Well, $e^{if}$ is then bounded in the upper half plane. Don't know where that leads - just throwing it out there.

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2634606/42969

Comment: @MartinR thanks! That's what I want